# Request/response for authentication for Office365 federated case

Tags: authentication, office365, adfs, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I have following setup. Office365 is configured with federated identity. Let say Outlook client is trying to authenticate to Office365. It (some mix of Office365 and AzureAD) will authenticate to ADFS (using WS-Federation protocol).

I want to create simple server which mimics WF-Federation interface (so Office365/AzureAD will authenticate against my server).

I am looking for example request and response of this protocol for such a case. Just to make sure which parts of WS-Federation is used. And I will try to find open source code which covers it.

I am reading through:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html

On one hand it covers the whole WS-Federation. However, it has gazillion options and it's not clear which part of it is used by Office365/AzureAD/ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using OpenId Connect rather than WS-Federation.  There is a lot more current documentation on it, and it is the preferred authentication protocol for Azure AD moving forward.  You can find many examples here:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples

And this one might be a good one to start with.
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

If you are not developing on .NET then you can use these samples to generate example messages.  There are also many 3rd party libraries and SDKs for non-Microsoft platforms that will likely also work.